# Edit each row separately in data table Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

My goal is to get the editable column in every row in Vuetify's data table. I used v-edit-dialog to edit this value. Initially, I populate rows with a number from  a different component passed as a prop - ***quantity***. Then I need to edit each row independently. I am thinking about a new Array to save the edited value, but I receive a huge array of nulls.

```
<td class="text-xs-right">
 <v-edit-dialog
   large
   lazy
   persistent
 >
   <div class="text-xs-center">{{ QuantityDisplay() }}</div>
   <template v-slot:input>
     <v-text-field
       v-model="inputQuality"
       :rules="[max5chars]"
       maxlength="5"
       single-line
     />
   </template>
 </v-edit-dialog>
</td>
```

```
props: {
  quantity: {
     type: Number,
     default: 0
  }    
},
data () {
  return {
    newQuantity: [],
    inputQuality: null
  }
},
methods: {
  QuantityDisplay () {
    this.newQuantity.push(this.inputQuality)
    return this.newQuantity
  }
}
```

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/kamor04/pen/GRpqYwB

Comment: Please clarify. Do you mean you want to edit each column in the row separately? How is what you're attempting different than [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#crud-actions)?

Comment: You need inline content editing. Its already made by the vuetify team. Please check https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#content-editing

Comment: Thank you guys for the answer. Okay, I need to clarify. I am passing a value in prop and assign it to every row in one column, because I set to the default value earlier . When I use v-edit-dialog and change the value, it's gonna change in every row, but I want to edit every row separately. Tha's why I trying to save it in a different variable, or maybe array, I don't know what is the correct way.

Comment: You should create a codepen of this to show what is the current behaviour and what you are expecting.

Comment: Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/kamor04/pen/GRpqYwB
You can see current behaviour when I receive trash data with many nulls, or you can change variables to {{ quantity }} and   v-model="quantity" in v-edit-dialog to see default behaviour. My goal is to edit each row in the last column independently.